# ViewScoped bean losing its state after clicking a commandLink

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, icefaces, icefaces-3

I'm using Icefaces 3.2 along with JSF 2.1.8. I have the below views included in the main xhtml page. It looks like `myViewBean` which is `@ViewScoped` is losing it's state after the link `myLink` is clicked. The `actionListener` has logic to get the `myViewBean` and set the required list of items. During the render response phase, the `myViewBean` seems to have empty `empList`. If the `@ViewScoped` is changed to `@SessionScoped`, it works in the expected way, but I have 10 other beans all of which need to be changed to SessionScoped. What makes the bean lose its state? Or is there any other way to make use of ViewScoped?

**main.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" >
<f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
        </h:head>
        <h:body id="bodyId" bgcolor="white">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <ice:panelGroup>
                        <ice:form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <ui:include src="myTabs.xhtml"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </ice:form>
                    </ice:panelGroup>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**myTabs.xhtml**

```
<f:subview 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<div>
    <table class="icePnlTbSet" id="myTabSet"
        border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- My Tab 1 -->
                            <td class="icePnlTb" style="vertical-align: bottom;" title="tab1">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="LftTop"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                        <td class="MidTop"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                        <td class="RtTop"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="LftMid"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                        <td class="MidMid">
                                            <ice:commandLink id="myLink" value="MyTab 1" title=""
                                                actionListener="#{mySessionBean.tabChanged}">
                                                <f:param value="0" name="tab" />
                                            </ice:commandLink>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="RtMid"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="LftBtm"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                        <td class="MidBtm"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                        <td class="RtBtm"><img alt="" src="/images/spacer.gif "
                                            width="4" height="1" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            <!-- Repeat for n tabs -->
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<ui:include src="tabcontent1.xhtml" />
 </f:subview>
```

**tabcontent1.xhtml**

```
<f:subview 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:dataTable  id="empTable" value="#{myViewBean.empList}"
            var="emp">
            ...
    </ice:dataTable>
</ice:panelGroup>
</f:subview>
```

Answer (score 0):

A @ViewScoped bean will only hold data if you return null or void from action methods (which will navigate back to the same page), once you navigate away from the view the data is lost.

May be you can try @RequestScoped.

Comment: I don't have any action here, does it mean the same as returning null or void?

Comment: Since you are getting away from the view the data is lost, which will not happen in the @SessionScoped (the data will be preserved till session is active).

Comment: How can I stay on the same view? I know there is a bug that, if we use `c:if` or so, the `@ViewScoped` wouldn't work, is my case one of a kind?

Comment: I also seem to be on the same view, only the `subview` is kind of changing?!